# What kind of raster mosaicking to use in land cover analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, mosaic, land-cover, ecognition

I have to mosaic two rasters (Landsat ETM+ scenes) to one single image and then analyse its land cover. Which option to use to avoid seeing a distinct line in the place where two different scenes/rasters are joined? I am using ArcGIS 10.0 and eCognition.

Comment: Do both images have the same pixel resolution?  What have you tried that shows a distinct line?

Comment: Both have the same resolution, I have tried mosaic to new raster first/last. I am not sure If I can do blend or average because they change the pixel number and I fear it would have effect on subsequent classification.

Comment: Would you mind to model/code the analysis? Than you could run it separately on each raster. After you have canged it to land cover categories, mosacing should be easier.

Comment: Were the scenes acquired at different time periods? If so, you will need to atmospherically correct them. Dark object subtraction is a common method for this.

Comment: I thought about the idea to classify each scene separately, but again there is an issue of the seam - it's always far from perfect. The scenes were acquired at different period, I will look into dark object subtraction. I have meddled with histograms and histogram matching in ArcGIS - could that be the way to go? Also, I am trying to mosaic scenes, so I have to apply corrections to each channel separately? Times the number of scenes? This is what and where I have been doing the histogram changes: https://olimpijada.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/seam_landsat.jpg